# i cant find the problem ScreenManager in kivymd

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

can you plz tell me the problem
in this code forsome reason it is not showing anything in screen

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv='''

ScreenManager:
    page_f:
    page_s:
        
<page_f>:
    name: 'page_f'
    MDFlatButton:
        text: 'go'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'page_s'
<page_s>:
    name: 'page_s'
    MDFlatButton:
        text: 'back'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'page_f'
'''

class page_f(Screen):
    pass


class page_s(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(page_f(name='page_f'))
sm.add_widget(page_s(name='page_s'))

class main(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main().run()
```

'''please ignore this this is becouse of a error iam gating while uploding question'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file) a class name in `kvlang` should be capitalized in order to avoid syntax error.

Thus the screen named `page_f` can be `Page_f` or any valid name following above mentioned rule. You should also make this changes in python.

As a side note, since you've already defined the root (`ScreenManager`) in `kvlang` you don't need the following code block anymore.

```py
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(page_f(name='page_f'))
sm.add_widget(page_s(name='page_s'))
```